# Can't get transactions - 0 returned

Tags: yodlee

I'm attempting to get transactions on an account previously added (more than a few days ago). 
The account was added to a test account on our sandbox but the account is real.
I use **executeUserSearchRequest** to initiate the search, with the parameters shown in the image below (screenshot from PhpStorm, while debugging).

The result can also be seen on the screenshot.

Please note that I've also attempted fetching transactions for another account on a different financial institution (that was added to the customer account on Yodlee again several weeks ago). It also returns no results.

When both accounts were added, they were added using **addItemForContentService1** with a parameter to refresh right after adding (**startRefreshItemOnAddition**=true).

What can be the reason for this 'no transactions' reply? (although we know that there were transactions on those accounts).

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot it seems like you are filtering the transactions based on the containerType= 'stocks', this will return transactions for all the investment accounts for that user.
Also, you are passing the itemAccountId.identifier which is for a specific account.

It would be great if you check followings:

1. The actual account aggregated is an investment account?
2. The itemAccountId is correct for that account?

Else, you can just remove the itemAccountId.identifier param as it is non-mandatory field and try. You should get some transactions in response.

Comment: Yes, our interest is solely in investment accounts information. The issue was with the itemAccountId. From all my tests I seem to have taken wrong account id. After pulling **all** transactions for all accounts I was able to see this. Thanks for the help!